# App crashes on adding second navHostFragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments

Due to a condition, I need two `navHostFragment` in two different activities in my app.
Everything works fine until I add a second `navhostframent` in my app, which creates an `inflateexception` with error:

```
Binary XML file line #36: Duplicate id 0x7f09018a, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
```

Following is my second navhost fragment:

```
    <fragment
                android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_supervisor"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNav"
                android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph_supervisor" />
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you post all of your `xml`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you have used <**fragment**>.
You can include <**fragment**> in XML to embed fragment instance inside of the layout.
What I can suggest is to **create a whole new layout** for your fragment and not use <**fragment**>.
**EDIT**
Create a separate layout and then embed your fragment instance inside it for example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_supervisor"
           android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNav"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph_supervisor" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate